# Nudist alien scene in a zombie movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

A group of survivors of a zombie outbreak encounter a group of aliens.  I remember the aliens accidentally caused the zombie outbreak and are trying to cure people with some kind of glowing rain, the aliens make the rain start and one of them takes off its robe to try and make the humans understand the rain is good.

The alien language is shown as subtitles and after the humans leave one of the still clothed aliens tells the naked one to put its clothes back on and the naked alien says "I am comfortable with who I am".

This scene is literally the only thing I can remember about this movie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be this film from 2003: *Undead*?

Synopsis from [Wikipedia's article on the film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undead_(film)):

> Later, they are confronted by glowing, hooded figures. One by one, the
>   group is either killed or pulled up into the clouds until only Rene is
>   left. The aliens stop her and she is sprayed with the rain-like
>   chemical, which turns out to be a cure for the infection. The Aliens
>   are actually there to keep the zombie infection from spreading. The
>   "abducted" are floating in suspended animation above the clouds to
>   keep them safe.

Comment: Aye thats it, its funny after you find something it seems so simple.